# Image resizing command not working in Magento 2.1.6

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm trying to run this `php bin/magento catalog:images:resize` in my `magento 2.1.6` but I'm getting following error

> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error:
>   Premature end of JPEG file  in
>   vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php
>   on line 65

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue in image resizing in magento 2.1.6 so please upgrade it with latest version or add this `EE-MAGETWO-67805.patch` patch.

Please check below url for more information regarding image resizing issue in magento 2.1.6
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/tech_bull_216-imageresize.html